# Why can my subscribers create new posts for review?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

My subscribers seem to have permission to create posts. After reading the [documentation on capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#subscriber), this shouldn't be the case. Subscribers should only be able to manage their own profile.

I have tested this with all plugins disabled and using the default 2022 theme, and new users are still able to create posts.

How do I troubleshoot this, since it doesn't seem to be a theme or plugin issue? Is this a bug in the latest release, perhaps?

Comment: are they creating them in the WP Admin area? Or are you just seeing new posts appear with subscribers as the author? Have you been making modifications to roles and capabilities? If it was a bug in the latest release it would have a Trac ticket and millions of sites would have been affected but I have seen no evidence of this

Comment: I'm not seeing any posts yet, but I want to be pro-active in preventing this. No, I haven't made any modifications to roles/capabilities, and I've switched to the default theme with no plugins at all, and it still happens.

Comment: and there are no modifications to files in the `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` folders? Do you mean there are no modifications or that there are no _current_ modifications to roles and capabilities? What you are describing is not normal. Also you did not answer my question about _where_ they have permission to create them, is this in WP Admin?

Comment: Yes, they can create them in WP-Admin, after logging in. I haven't made any modifications to wp-admin or wp-includes, but just to be sure, I have reinstalled v5.9.3 from the wp-admin interface. I have made no modifcations at all to roles/capabilities, but I don't know if any plugins might have done so (hence turning them all off). I know this isn't normal, and the fact that it's happening with no plugins and the 2022 theme is even more bizarre.

Comment: I've just had a look at {prefix}_user_roles in the options table, and the culprit is there, I think. There's an `edit_post` capability in the subscriber role: s:10:"subscriber";a:2:`{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:3:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;}}` Now to find what plugin put that in there.

Comment: Having exact same issue. Started about two months ago. Subscriber can now make post. Happening on two different installations on two different hosts. No plugins for users installed, User sign-up is set to Subscriber. New Subscriber retains role as Subscriber, yet is able to make posts.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255883)